# Getting key => value from json array passed from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to get an array from PHP and to manipulate it further using jQuery. In my PHP file i do `echo json_encode($data)` and when i put an alert in my response in jQuery i get:

```
[
    {
        "CustomerID": "C43242421",
        "UserID": "432421421",
        "Customer": "rqewrqwreeqwr",
        "Add1": "rqwerqwreqwrqwrqwr",
        "Add2": "&nbsp;",
        "Add3": "&nbsp;",
        "Phone": "4131231",
        "Fax": "532442141",
        "Contact": "reqwrqwrw",
        "Email": "gfdgdsg",
        "PaymentTerm": null,
        "Country": "3231",
        "City": "111",
        "Zip": "&nbsp;"
    }
]
```

, wich is a valid json array. Now what i try to do further is get the pairs as key => value as i would in an associative array in php.

```
$.post("templates/test.php",
    {data: query,
     cond: $(this).text(),
     action: 'select'
     },
function(res) {
    alert(res) //outputs what i pasted above
    $.each($.parseJSON(res), function(key, value) {
        alert(key + value);
        //this outputs: 0[object Object]
});
```

Removing the `$.parseJSON` in the above function gives me a `invalid 'in' operand e on jquery.min.js(line 3)` in Firebug error log.Can you assist me with my troubles?

Comment: That's an array `[]` containing one object `{}`. You must access the first element of the array `parseJSON(res)[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var r = $.parseJSON(res);

$.each(r[0], function(key, value) {
        alert(key + value);

});
```

Comment: Yep, this works. Thank you very much! I tried directly putting `$.parseJSON(res[0]);` but i got `JSON.parse: unexpected end of data` and didn't try it any other way :) Thanks again!
And now i see i had to do it like `$.parseJSON(res)[0];` :D

Answer (score 1):

The result of `$.parseJSON(res)` is an array, containing a single element (an object). When you iterate over that array (using `$.each`), `value` represents the entire object that's stored at the current index of the array. You'll need to iterate over that object to output its properties:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(res)[0], function(key, value) {
    alert(key + ' = ' + value);
});
```

If you have an array with multiple objects inside it, this more general code should output the key-value pairs for all of them:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(res), function(index, arrayObject) {
    $.each(arrayObject, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ' = ' + value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = $.parseJSON(res);

for (var i = 0; l = res.length; i < l; i++) {
   data = res[i];
   customer = data.Customer;
```

}

You have there an Array of Objects. You can iterate through the array of objects just like the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('your-json-string-file.php', function (data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert(key +'=>'+ val)
  });

});
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can get some kind of object from json:

```
function parse_json(res)
{
  try{
    return eval('(' + response + ')');
  }
  catch(e){
    // invalid json
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question at all, since they've already converted the JSON string to the object it represents (that's what `$.parseJSON()` does).